# Как скопировать полный путь до файла в ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, файловая-система

Как скопировать полный путь до файла (каталога) из менеджера в ubuntu?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ткнуть туда мышью не получается текстовая строка? Или в значок поиска справа

Comment: @Эникейщик неа, оно не активное, значок поиска очищает строку.

Comment: какой файл-менеджер?

Comment: @Эникейщик Files. 3.36.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПКМ на строке, и нажать `CTRL + L`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]